# "It's black's turn" or "it's blacks turn"?

Tags: orthography, possessives, apostrophe

Is it *black's turn* to move in chess, or is it *blacks turn*?

Comment: No, it's white's turn. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The turn belongs to the black side, so the possessive is called for:  "It's black's turn."

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'Black's turn'?